# Javascript assignment before foreach (I don't know what it's called)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, syntax

I'm going through some example code for looping through directories in Chrome App API and I've come across a statement I haven't seen before and don't know what to search.

```
function recurseDirectory(dirEntry, callback) {
    var dirsLeft = 1;
    var rootEntries;
    let helper = (dirEntry, isRoot) => {
        dirEntry.createReader().readEntries(entries => {
            dirsLeft--;

            if (isRoot) {
                rootEntries = entries;
            }
            //This line is what I'm confused about
            (dirEntry.entries = entries).forEach(entry => {
                if (entry.isDirectory) {
                    dirsLeft++;
                    helper(entry);
                }
            });

            if (!dirsLeft) {
                callback(rootEntries);
            }
        });
    }

    helper(dirEntry, true);
}
```

I can't run this code yet since it's just a snippet so I'm still dissecting it.

The part that I don't know is `(dirEntry.entries = entries).forEach {...}`. I tried looking up `assignment foreach`, `equal foreach` but no results for this.

What is this operation/syntax called and what does it do?

Comment: In case you want to know what is it called, it's the "grouping operator": https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-grouping-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an ordinary variable assignment - however, placing it in brackets means that you're assigning `dirEntry.entries` the value of `entries`, *and* iterating through `entries` with the same statement - it's just shorthand for:

```
dirEntry.entries = entries;
entries.forEach(entry => {...});
```

Comment: No worries @IshouldchangemyUsername, always glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something else but an Assignment Expression. `(dirEntry.entries = entries)` will return the value of `entries` on which `forEach` will be applied and in also `dirEntry.entries` to `entires`. Its doing to things in one line.

- Changing the value of `data.entires` to `entires`
- return `entires` on which `forEach` is applied.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an assignment and the immediate execution of `forEach` over the array which is now referenced by `entries` and `dirEntry.entries`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a lazy guy trying to save himself couple key press. It's equiv to

```
dirEntry.entries = entries;
entries.forEach(...)
```